# downloaded zip file corrupted in server using react axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, blob, zip

this is the code I have used to download the zip file.

```
axios.post(url, postData, { responseType: 'blob',
        headers:{
            'Content-Type':"application/json",
            'x-correlation-id': 'EEBO-'+ uuidv4(),
            'x-source-id': 'EEBO',
            'x-source-country' : 'CN',
            'x-source-version': Constants.BO_VERSION,
            'x-source-date-time' :  FormatCurrentDateToISOFormat(),
            'x-acc-op' : jwt,
        }
 
     })
         .then(({ data }) =>  {
            console.log("gettoken",data);
            // data.auth = true;
            var fileURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([data]));
            var fileLink = document.createElement('a');
           
            fileLink.href = fileURL;
            fileLink.setAttribute('download', 'AdminReport_'+current_date+'.zip');
            document.body.appendChild(fileLink);
            
            fileLink.click();
            
        })
```

in my machine it is working properly(able to download and open the excel file), unfortunately unable to **open downloaded zip file** from server(we are using openshift).

I can see in the console:
in machine console: `gettoken Blob {size: 3809, type: "application/zip"}`
server console : `gettoken Blob {size: 3809, type: "text/html"}`

I have no idea what is wrong, please help me.

Comment: Looks like your server is not responding to the request with the appropriate Content-Type header.

Comment: Then how can I change the logic to read the content type by server?

Answer (score 0):

```
import 'date-fns';
import React from 'react';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import DateFnsUtils from '@date-io/date-fns';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Icon from '@material-ui/core/Icon';
import {moment} from 'moment';
import {
    MuiPickersUtilsProvider,
    KeyboardTimePicker,
    KeyboardDatePicker,
} from '@material-ui/pickers';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    button: {
        margin: theme.spacing(1),
    },
}));

export default function MaterialUIPickers() {
    // The first commit of Material-UI
    const [selectedDate, setSelectedDate] = React.useState(null);
    const [endDate, setEndDate] = React.useState(null);
    const classes = useStyles();

  
    
   

    const handleDateChange = (date) => {
        setSelectedDate(date);
    };

    const handleEndDateChange = (date) => {
        setEndDate(date);
    };


    return (
        <div class="row">
            <MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils}>
                <Grid container justifyContent="center">
                    <KeyboardDatePicker
                        margin="normal"
                        maxDate={new Date()}
                        id="date-picker-dialog"
                        label="Start Date"
                        format="MM-dd-yyyy"
                        value={selectedDate}
                        onChange={handleDateChange}
                        KeyboardButtonProps={{
                            'aria-label': 'change date',
                        }}
                    />
                    <span>  </span>
                    <KeyboardDatePicker
                        margin="normal"
                        maxDate={new Date()}
                        id="date-picker-dialog"
                        label="End Date"
                        format="MM-dd-yyyy"
                        value={endDate}
                        onChange={handleEndDateChange}
                        KeyboardButtonProps={{
                            'aria-label': 'change date',
                        }}
                    />
                </Grid>
                <Grid container justifyContent="center">
                    {selectedDate && endDate && <Button
                        variant="contained"
                        color="primary"
                        className={classes.button}
                        endIcon={<Icon>send</Icon>}
                    >
                        Send
                    </Button>}
                </Grid>

            </MuiPickersUtilsProvider>

        </div>
    );

}
```

1. npm i --save date-fns@next @date-io/date-fns@1.x
2. npm install date-fns @types/date-fns
3. npm install  @material-ui/core@next
4. npm install @material-ui/pickers
5. npm i @date-io/date-fns@1.x date-fns
6. npm i @date-io/moment@1.x moment
7. npm install @material-ui/core